# How can I send post messages from iFrames with different domains?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I'm trying to communicate with [post messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) between a parent window and an iFrame. The frames are in different domains (my domain, and a Google Maps iFrame).

Sending a post message from the parent window to the iFrame works correctly:

```
const iFrameNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.iframe);
iFrameNode.contentWindow.postMessage({data: JSON.stringify(data), type: 'GET_MARKERS'}, '*');
```

But when I'm trying to send a reply to the parent window:

```
window.parent.postMessage({
    type: 'MARKERS',
    data: {
        mapInstance: window.googleMapsInstance,
        markersInstance: window.googleMapsMarkerInstance
    }
}, '*')
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [NOTHING here?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biframe%5D+Blocked+a+frame+with+origin+from+accessing+a+cross-origin+frame)

Comment: @mplungjan NONE with iFrame to parent issue. Any suggestion buddy?

Comment: what if you load it onto a real server, i.e. not localhost

Comment: What is the domain of `window.parent`?

Comment: Did you set X-Frame-Options in your iframe server?

Comment: @mplungjan Just did. Still the same error except the origin value.

Comment: @ZhaoHainan I can't, it's a google-maps iframe.